# I need a custom generic power method

Tags: java, generics

this is my homework that I need to create a generic method to calculate the power.
Same as Math.pow(x,y); 
But x should generic and extends Number, y is an int number.

I can only push here.

```
public static <T extends Number> double power(T x, int y){


    double result = 0;

    for(int i=0; i<y; i++){

    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: This is homework, so I won't give you the answer, but look at the methods on the Number class, http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is homework, but I see you already wrote something. Here is my version (Caveat: my java is rusty).

```
public static <T extends Number> double power(T x, int y){
    /* I don't feel like calling this in a loop */ 
    double dx = x.doubleValue();
    double result = 1;

    for(int i=0; i<y; i++){
        result *= dx;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Will `double` be enough to contain all classes that extend Number?

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will vote up as soon as I got enough reputation.